# Lose communication with USB device

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a VB.net program that uses a USB relay switch.  The program works well however every now and then I get an error saying access to the port is denied and asking if I have sufficient privileges to access this resource (see picture). [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vy2X.png)  I am log on with all administrative rights.

Does anybody know how to deal with this error message.  It is causing a big problem with my data collection is causing me to lose hours of data.

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: When do you get this Error , when the device is removed?

Comment: No, when the program is running.  My program needs to turn on an air supply every two minutes.  I start by opening my port, then I activate my USB relay, and then I close the port.  Once in a while when I go to open my port I get the error that I posted in the picture.  I never need to disconnect my device.